# Add custom headers to Client Credentials with Client Secret Flow

Tags: custom, header, credentials, client

I am trying to use Named Credentials with external credentials to call an endpoint. In order to retrieve the access token, **I need to pass a custom header** in addition to the client ID and the client secret.

I want to use use the **Client Credentials with Client Secret Flow**.

I found an article online that suggests if my token requires a custom header, as is the case for me, I need to use Apex.

[image]

So I am wondering if the external credential can natively handle the custom header to retrieve the access token, or should I use custom Apex as suggested in the artcile ?

Comment: Client Credentials flow as described in the spec does not have your custom header, so you can't use External/Named Creds as is / out of the box

Comment: @identigral , can't we add custom headers using the "Custom headers" section on the external credentials layout?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_cred_custom_headers.htm&type=5 has the answers you're looking for